# Could SARS-COV-2 antibodies disappear 16 months after infection

Tags: sars-cov-2

What is the possibility, based on current medical knowledge, that SARS-COV-2 antibodies are no longer present after 16 months?

How would this compare to what we know about the immune response to other coronaviruses?

Comment: Is it _possible_? Yes, it is, but no one here can tell you if you did or did not have COVID last year. There are many questions here related to COVID, immunity and testing that you might find useful, but the short answer is it's just not known how long the immune response to COVID remains detectable.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not asking for personal medical advice, if wanted medical advice I would and have asked my doctor who, as @CareyGregory points out told me 'that it's not yet know how long the immune response to SARS-COV-2 lasts'. 

I have not discussed my symptoms in the question nor have requested personal medical advice. The question clearly asks, Could a SARS-COV-2 Antibody test return negative 16 months after infection?

I realise this is a very difficult question to ask, that's why I put it out to an expert community I respect rather than reddit

Comment: I shall remove the back story, which I felt added context to the question, so it no longer sounds like I'm asking for personal medical advice.

Comment: How do I vote to reopen this question?

Comment: The way the question was originally worded it essentially asked us to speculate on whether you had COVID or not, so it was both asking for a diagnosis and opinion-based. It's okay the way it is now so I'll reopen